# Can we prevent duplicate cases which are built by the email to case using email services?

Tags: apex-code

using the salesforce Email Services can we do means prevent duplicate cases and How please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your pain.  My users often complain that our service email address is included in email conversations and this creates a case for each email received. They then have to spend hours merging the cases and pulling out the relavant material. Worse, they have to manually move email attachments from the duplicate child case to the parent case.

One solution is to purchase an AppExchange application that provides a custom email handler that works well.  Look for the Email to Case premium on the AppExchange.

https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001R5cyEAC

Or you can do what I did and build a custom email handler.  See my blog for the code which is currently working in our organization:

http://sforcehacks.blogspot.com/2012/01/email-to-case-can-create-too-many-cases.html

Comment: hai bryan thank you for your answer and it really help me and your blog is also helpful for the starters...